# list of available targets for openUrlExternally

Tags: application-development

Using Qt for my ubuntu touch application and I'm having trouble getting it to launch the text messaging application. using Qt.openUrlExternally('sms:'+carduserphone)

carduserphone being a variable that stores the telephone number. tel: and mailto: work perfectly.

I've also tried "text:","txt:","mms:" all for not. So is there a list of available targets for openUrlExternally, and more importantly is there one for Ubuntu in general. Might be fun to see what other things I can launch.

Answer (score 0):

So doing some digging around on the phone I found the answer. "message" is the magic word. 
You can find the system url dispatchers in the folder /usr/share/url-dispatcher/urls

and 3rd party applications store them

/opt/click.ubuntu.com//name.url-dispatcher

on Ubuntu proper it can be found in

/usr/share/applications

among other places I'm sure.